# How should I have handled this edit

Tags: discussion, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18427032

This is the first time I've ever edited anything on StackExchange.  In the comments on the answer the OP was saying that she was getting an error after trying his code, while the person that wrote the answer admitted it was for SQL (server) and may not work in Access.  Should I have just edited the original code block in the answer and not added a second code block?  I didn't feel right submitting it as a separate answer since I was piggybacking off the original answer

Comment: And the author accepted the change. You handled it well. That's collaboration at work.

Comment: If the author did not accept it (with his definite-accept privilege), this would definitely have been rejected for the reasons it was rejected by two other reviewers.

Comment: Help on editing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I didn't feel right submitting it as a separate answer since I was piggybacking off the original answer

But that's precisely what you should have done if you want to add your own additional solution to a problem.  If you're posting an answer that's using the work of another answer then you need to cite the content that is not your own work appropriately.

Comment: The author considers that this edit is fine. There's no need to prohibit it. Focus more on the unqualified reviewers instead of the qualified editor.

Comment: @Braiam If the author of the answer wants to edit their answer to use a solution someone else mentioned to them, that's fine, but *they* need to be the one to include something like that in their answer.  Editing it into their answer for them is not.  You of course know that this is the policy.  I know you don't care, but you know that it's the policy regardless.  The appropriate way for someone to post their own new answer is to post their own new answer, not to edit their own new answer into someone else's existing answer, as the qualified reviewers *correctly identified*.

Comment: " Editing it into their answer for them is not." "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." Maybe this is not the site for you Servy.

Comment: @Braiam And yet that doesn't mean that any edit to any post is okay.  There are certain types of edits that are appropriate, and some that aren't.  If you are not comfortable with the idea that you aren't allowed to edit anything that you want into someone else's post, and that edits are limited to improvements to *someone else's answer*, rather than a way to *add your own new answer*, this may not be the site for you.  Maybe this is not the site for you Braiam.

Comment: "doesn't mean that any edit to any post is okay" actually it is: *Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so.*

Comment: @Braiam If you ignore all of the other rules that are in place around editing and only read the one sentence, sure.  If you actually read the rules, then no, that's not the case.